# How to convert the logical constrains into a set of linear (integer) constraints?

Tags: python, linear-programming

I am using python pulp to solve a linear integer program problem in the paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07118, but some constraints from the paper are logical constraints, such as logical **OR** operator,

[image]

and logical **AND** operator,

[image]

Comment: Edit your post to have some questions and be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think once you know how to model `z = x ∧ y` and `z = x ∨ y` (x,y,z all binary variables) you are good to go.

1. `z = x ∧ y` can be modeled as:

   ```
      z ≤ x
      z ≤ y
      z ≥ x + y - 1
   ```
2. `z = x ∨ y` is

   ```
      z ≥ x
      z ≥ y
      z ≤ x + y
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helps me a lot.